# Is there a way to download files from Azure Cloud Shell?

Tags: azure, azure-storage-files, azure-cloud-shell

I am trying to get credentials for my Azure Kubernetes Cluster. Ran the script to fetch details on Azure cloud shell and got a .config file. I wonder if there is a way to download the file from my Azure Cloud Shell session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Azure Cloud Shell, you need to create an Azure File Share or use the existed. Cloud shell will mount File Share to the system. And the mount path you can use command `mount` to take a look. The result will like this:
[image]
[image]

As I suggest, you can copy the .config file to the path like this: `/home/RG/clouddrive/.cloudconsole`, then you can download the file from File Share.

For more details, you can take a look at another case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181200/azure-cloud-shell-file-share-contains-5gb-img-file/51182221#51182221).

Comment: If the answer is helpful to you? Please let me know.

Comment: I'm glad the answer is helpful to you! :-)

Answer (score 38):

At the cloud shell prompt just type: `download yourfilename`

Comment: Very simple. Worked like a charm. Thank you for sharing your suggestion.

Comment: I'm running the command "download $HOME/.kube/config". But, I don't find any file getting downloaded to my machine. May I know where the file gets download?

Comment: @BNJ hit the same issue, you have to be doing this from the web browser for this to work (not the Windows Terminal).

Answer (score 2):

1. List your files

[Azure Cloud Shell File listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TPac.png)

You may notice the clouddrive folder (check image link above). This folder is mounted to an Azure File Share, as specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#how-cloud-shell-storage-works

2. Get Azure File Share Information:

[Azure File Share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8wWV.png)

With the Get-CloudDrive command you obtain the Azure File Share metadata that will help you to find the download page for your files in Azure Portal. Alternatively you may use the df command

[image: df command output]

3. Login to Azure Portal and locate the Azure File Share:

[Azure File Share at Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isoWD.png)
[image: Azure storage account]