# how to download the files present in cloud drive of azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I have created 2 instances of Azure Linux VMs using Azure PowerShell and their Public, Private Key files are saved in the cloud drive.

**Path**:

```
Private key is saved to /home/user/.ssh/1694408615
Public key is saved to /home/user/.ssh/1694408615.pub
```

[image]

How to download these files from the cloud drive?

So that I can make use of those key while connecting to Linux VMs.

**Update**:
I come to know the command i.e., `download filename` - Its worked.

Now the question is - "How to download multiple files or all the files present in Azure CloudShell drive?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the question is - "How to download multiple files or all the files present in Azure CloudShell drive?"

To copy all files from `Azure Cloud Shell` to a local path, follow the steps below.

1. First, copy all files to clouddrive using the command below.

```bash
cp -r  /home/user/SSH   /home/user/clouddrive/
```

In your case command is below.

```
   cp -r  /home/user/.ssh   /home/user/clouddrive/
```

2. Once you've copied the files to clouddrive, verify the files by navigating to clouddrive

```
    cd clouddrive
    ls
```

**Output:**
[image]

3. Download the files from `Azure File share` to local using `Azcopy` command.

   **Generate SAS Token inside Storage account.**

[image]

```
 azcopy cp   "https://csg10032002cghg3ea4.file.core.windows.net/?<Your-sastoken>" "<Local-Path\SSH" --recursive=true
```

[image]

All files are downloaded from `Cloud Shell` to `Local`.

[image]

Reference: [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181200/azure-cloud-shell-file-share-contains-5gb-img-file/51182221#51182221) by `Charles Xu`

Comment: Thanks @VenkatV. It's a clear-cut steps in the Solution. Appreciated.

Comment: If possible, could you help me in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77079395/22396225) also.